# Чем отличаются имена входа в MS SQL Server от пользователей БД?

Tags: sql, sql-server, авторизация, users

Да, по этой теме миллион статей на Google. Но каждая из них сводится к тому, что "имя входа – это для сервера, а пользователь – для конкретной базы". Это я понял. Но вот незадача. Я захожу в SQL Server Management Studio с именем входа. И когда я произвожу какие-либо манипуляции с БД, никто "не интересуется", от имени какого пользователя я хочу это сделать. Вследствие чего отпадает всякий смысл в пользователях, если разграничение прав идёт только на уровне имён входа.

Попытаюсь объяснить другими словами, если вдруг сказанное выше непонятно: зачем вообще нужны пользователи БД, если с них всё равно нельзя авторизоваться и если при выполнении тех или иных действий с БД имеет значение только имя входа? Например, я создаю одно имя входа и к нему несколько пользователей одной БД. Раздаю пользователям разные права на эту БД. Но когда я захочу сделать что-либо с БД, от имени какого из пользователей я буду это делать?? Чьи права применятся при проверке правомерности моих действий, если на одном имени входа завязано несколько пользователей???

Comment: *Например, я создаю одно имя входа и к нему несколько пользователей одной БД* - например, так сделать не получится

Comment: примеры статей таких приведите?

Comment: @teran https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/cf963f48-7df4-49b5-84f8-a4485559e08d/1054109010831080109510801077-10801084107710851080?forum=sqlru

Comment: @DenisRubashkin тогда тем более, какой смысл вообще в именах входа?? почему нельзя сразу авторизоваться от пользователя БД? я понимаю, что вопрос, вероятно, глупый и экспертам по СУБД это ясно как день, но я уже несколько дней тщетно пытаюсь это понять.

Comment: мб смысл в переносимости? когда база мигрирует на другой сервер, то пользователи БД вместе с их настройками мигрируют вместе с ними. Далее вы можете связать логины сервера с этими пользователями на новом месте. При этом сами учетные данные авторизации остаются на своих серверах. так что политика разграничения на уровне базы независима и отделена от сервера.

Comment: Сервер и база данных это не одно и то же, вообще баз данных на сервере больше одной. Имя входа и база данных - это securables (не знаю как этому правильный перевод подобрать, мб сущности) уровня сервера. У имени входа может быть доступ к некой БД, а может и не быть. Пользователь БД - это уже securable уровня БД и он храниться внутри БД,  то есть перемещается вместе с ней при переносе на другой сервер.

Comment: [SQL Server Access Control: The Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-access-control-basics/)